# Strange characters added when using 'xstring' functions in 'foreach'

Tags: unicode, foreach, xstring

I'm trying to create a macro which display a list of string and if a string start with '*', it apply specific style (like bold).

So I'm using a foreach and xstring macros but something goes wrong with strange characters displayed.

I made two cases, only the second one is not working but I need to figure out a solution in the configuration of the second case.

---

Configuration:

MacOS Monterey, shipset M1

LaTeX environnement installed from brew (mactex)

---

Case 1:

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xstring}

% Command
\newcommand{\simplelist}[1]{%
  \foreach \item in {#1}{
    \item
    \hspace{1cm}
  }
}

\newcommand{\enhancedlist}[1]{%
  \foreach \item in {#1}{%
    \IfSubStr{\item}{*}
      {\textbf{\StrGobbleLeft{\item}{1}}}
      {\item} 
    \hspace{1cm}
  }
}

% Document
\begin{document}
\StrGobbleLeft{*item1}{1}\par
\simplelist{item1,*item2,item3}\par
\enhancedlist{item1,*item2,item3}
\end{document}
```

**Build command**

```
latexmk -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf main
```

**Result**

[image: case 1 result]

---

Case 2:

**main_with_lib.tex**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{custom_library}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Example is working if removed
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{lato}

% Document
\begin{document}
\StrGobbleLeft{*item1}{1}\par
\simplelist{item1,item2,*item3}\par
\enhancedlist{item1,item2,*item3}
\end{document}
```

**custom_library.tex**

```
\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2018/04/01}{\UseRawInputEncoding}{}
\LoadClass{extarticle}

\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}

% Commands
\newcommand{\simplelist}[1]{%
  \foreach \item in {#1}{
    \item
    \hspace{1cm}
  }
}

\newcommand{\enhancedlist}[1]{
  \foreach \item in {#1}{
    \IfSubStr{\item}{*}
      {\textbf{\StrGobbleLeft{\item}{1}}}
      {\item} 
    \hspace{1cm}
  }
}
```

**Build command**

```
latexmk -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -pdf main_with_lib
```

**Result**

[image]

---

In case 2, it seems if I remove '\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}', it's working well.
But like I said, I'm using this code in a bigger project and I had to keep configuration as it's set in case 2.

Any ideas ? Explanations ? :)

Comment: accented A almost always implies UTF-8 is being mis-interpreted. you have `\UseRawInputEncoding` which disables LaTeX's encoding support, so bad effects are expected. `\UseRawInputEncoding` can be used in some legacy contexts to allow "competing" encoding packages, but if used on its own it basically breaks latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `{\item}` in your definition you have the control character U+2029 (PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR)

Normally if you use that character in LaTeX (here between []):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR [ ]
\end{document}
```

You get

```
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character   (U+2029)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR [ 
                                   ]
?
```

however Your document uses `\UseRawInputEncoding` which disables LaTeX's encoding support so the raw bytes that encode U+2029 are seen as three separate characters in whatever *font* encoding is current, so

No error but output

[image]

If you use OT1 encoding you get output

[image]

But it is not really an improvement, it is still typesetting nonsense characters but now warns

```
Missing character: There is no � in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no � in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no � in font cmr10!
```

as OT1 encoding has no accented characters.

---

So firstly you want to remove the U+2029 from the line

```
      {\item}
```

(you may find it easiest to delete the line and re-type)

Then remove

```
\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2018/04/01}{\UseRawInputEncoding}{}
```

which can never help here.

Not related to the error but I would not use `\item` as your local loop variable, it is a standard latex command so confuses anyone debugging this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! It worked.
I removed '\@ifl@t@r\fmtversion{2018/04/01}{\UseRawInputEncoding}{}' and retype '{item}' line.

Now, I just have to figure out how to see (paragraph separator) in my editor to avoid further issue.